# IndexOf array with strings as index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Probably ill advised, but I have an array with strings for indexes. Now I need to use `indexOf` and it doesn't work. The code below returns -1. Any way to get `b` out of this without rewriting everything?

```
x = [];
x['a'] = 0;
x['b'] = 1;
print(x.indexOf(1));
```

Comment: You're adding the properties `a` and `b` to your array (your array remains empty). You can get `b` by doing `x.b`.

Comment: You don't have an array here you have an object with properties...

Comment: As soon as you do `x['a'] = 0` the Array becomes an Object with a property `a`. That's Javascript's loose-typedness for ya. You'll have to write a method/function that iterates the properties with `for (prop in x)` to see if there's a property with value 1. Alternatively you could make functions to translate `a, b, c, ...` to `1, 2, 3, ...` and back. That way you could keep it an ACTUAL array.

Comment: The thing is, I know what the property is, but not the index? I'm looking for the index of 1, I need the program to tell me it's `b`.

Comment: Ah yes, that's confusing in my comment, I meant to say that in stead of having property `a`, you could say _"a is the first letter of the alphabet, therefor I will store whatever value it has in the array at index 1"_ and make a function like `alphabetIndexFor(letter)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue you are not understanding is that an Array *cannot* have strings as indexes. The syntax you are using is an alternate way of defining properties on to an object. All the previous suggestions people are giving you is probably confusing you more. Keep it simple. Arrays have number indexes.

```
// this is adding values to an array
var x = [];
x[0] = 'one';
x[1] = 'two';
console.log(x[0]);       // outputs 'one'

// this is adding a property to an object
var y = {};
y['width'] = 20;
y['height'] = 40;
console.log(y['width']); // outputs 20
console.log(y.height);   // outputs 40

// this is adding a property to our previous array 
// (because Arrays are objects too in JavaScript)
x['name'] = 'My Array';
console.log(x.name);     // outputs 'My Array'

x.indexOf('My Array');   // returns -1 because 'My Array' is not stored in the array
x.indexOf('two');        // returns 1 because that's the index of 'two' in the array
```

Comment: Got it. So, if I'm trying to find the property of an object that has a particular value, as @funkwurm said above, I'd use a for/in loop.

Comment: @AleshHoudek Yes, that is correct. However, you want to treat `for...in` loops cautiously because they will work up through an object's `prototype` chain (think inheritance) and loop over properties you aren't intending it to. The more properties that exist on an object and its prototypes, the slower the loop will perform. This is alleviated with appropriate use of the `hasOwnProperty()` method of the object you are looping on.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [];
x['a'] = 0;
x['b'] = 1;

 var valueIndex = Object.keys(x).map(function(prop){
   return x[prop]
 }).indexOf(1);

Object.keys(x)[valueIndex] //b
```

Unless it's really going to be in that order just do

```
Object.keys(x)[1]; //b
```

Answer (score 0):

Concrete code for the suggestion I made in comments, depending on the scenario this is easier or harder to implement in existing code than `for (prop in x)`:

```
function put(arr, letter, value) {
  arr[letter.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0)-96] = value;
}
function find(arr, value) {
  return String.fromCharCode(x.indexOf(value)+96);
}

x = [];
put(x, 'a', 0);
put(x, 'b', 1);
print(find(x, 1)); // gives b
```